# Can't submit a JQuery modal window under ie11

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, button

Instead of using the default "Submit" button of a JQuery modal window, I display a simple table with input fields and a standard submit button (simply because I like it better). The script runs fine under Chrome and Firefox, but under IE11 the button does not submit the form. I can press it, but nothing happens. (the modal window is closable so it works on some degree)

Javascript:

```
$('#loginModal').dialog({
     modal: true,
     autoOpen: false,
     resizable: false,
     title: "Enter your credentials"
 });
```

Html:

```
<div id="loginModal">
<table style="border:0px">
    <form action="/mypage/login" method="POST" class="inline" id="loginForm">
        <tr style="border:0px">
            <td style="border:0px">
                <label><b>Username:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td style="border:0px">
                <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:0px">
            <td style="border:0px">
                <label><b>Password:</b></label>
            </td>
            <td style="border:0px">
                <input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="15" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:0px">
            <td style="border:0px"></td>
            <td style="border:0px; float: right;margin-right: 1em;">
                <input type="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: which version of `Jquery`?

Comment: Have you activated the option to show Javascript errors?

Comment: I am very inexperienced in debugging things like that. I have turned on the IE console though. Once I open the modal window type something into the username field and press tab to go to the pw it gives an error though. The file name is: jquery.validate.min.js, highlighted line: "return $.event.handle.call(this,e)", error message: "Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: I have created a JSfiddle. Works fine under chrome, but doesnt under IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/3QT2U/